# Click in one slid and go to the other chart

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee

I have a pieChart with 2 slide and I want when I click in one slid, I can see a ComboChart.

I can do it with " URL and GET " for having second chart in other page but I want to have the two chart (pieChart, ComboChart) in one page. I don't know which function I can use in JavaScript?

---

```
<html>
  <head>

<?php
//Conection to DB
session_start();
pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=base_test user=postgres password=123456");

if (isset($_POST['uname']))
    {
       $uname=$_POST['uname'];
       $pass=$_POST['pass'];

       $q=pg_query("select name from admin where uname='$uname' and pass='$pass'");
       $n=pg_num_rows($q);
    if ($n>0)
        {
        $f=pg_fetch_row($q);
        $_SESSION['admin']=$f[0];
        }
    else
        {

                echo("Invalid user!");
                echo("<p><a href='ADMINISTRATION.php'>Come back to page administrateur</a></p>");
                echo("<img src='thinking minde.gif'  alt='thinking minde' width='400' height='400' />");

                 exit;
        }
    }

    // ?
if ($_SESSION['admin']!='' && $n>0 )
    {
                 echo("Welcome in data table : ".$_SESSION['admin']);

        $q='SELECT SUM("Facteur"),"building" from "Cout" where site=\''.$f[0].'\'GROUP BY("building")';
        $query=pg_query($q);
        $n=pg_num_rows($query);

    }


    ?>





    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });

  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
  });



      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'building');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Facteur');
    data.addColumn('string', 'URL');
    data.addRows([

        <?php
        for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
                {
                $f=pg_fetch_row($query);    
                echo("['".$f[1]."', ".$f[0].",'http://localhost/test_new/test5.php?name=$f[1]'],");
                //echo("['".$f[1]."', ".$f[0]."],'$ville'");
                }

        ?> 

    ]);

    // create a view to hide the URLs from the PieChart
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
        var sel = chart.getSelection();
        if (sel.length > 0) {
            // get the URL from the DataTable
            var url = data.getValue(sel[0].row, 2); 
        alert(data.getValue(sel[0].row, 0)); 
            // open URL in new tab
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        }

    })

    chart.draw(view, {
        height: 300,
        width: 400

    });
}

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});

    </script>




<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<?php
//session_start();
//print_r($_GET["name"]);
//echo $_GET["name"];

pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=base_test user=postgres password=123456") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

    $ville = ??????????????????????????????????;
    //$ville = "Maison pour tous";
    //$ville = say();

    $my_array = array();
    $q='SELECT "timestamp" from "Cout" where building=\''.$ville.'\' GROUP BY ("timestamp")';
    $query=pg_query($q);
    $n=pg_num_rows($query); 
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
        $f=pg_fetch_row($query);
        $my_array["timestamp"][]= $f[0];
    }

    $q='SELECT "name", "Facteur" from "Cout" where building=\''.$ville.'\'';
    $query=pg_query($q);
    $n=pg_num_rows($query); 
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
        $f=pg_fetch_row($query);
        $my_array[$f[0]][]= $f[1];
    }

    $q='SELECT "timestamp", sum("DJU") from "Cout" where building=\''.$ville.'\' GROUP BY ("timestamp")';
    $query=pg_query($q);
    $n=pg_num_rows($query); 
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
        $f=pg_fetch_row($query);
        $my_array["DJU"][]=$f[1];
    }

    $col_name = array();
    $col_name = array_keys($my_array);
/*
    $q='SELECT "name" from "Cout" where building=\'Maison pour tous\' GROUP BY ("name")';
    $query=pg_query($q);
    $n=pg_num_rows($query); 
    */
    ?>  


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          [
          <?PHP
            for($i=0; $i<count($col_name); $i++){
                $f=pg_fetch_row($query);
                echo("'".$col_name[$i]."'");
                if($i< count($col_name)-1){
                    echo(",  ");
                }
            }       
          ?>
          ],
          <?php
            for($j=0; $j<$n; $j++){
            ?>
                [
                <?php
                for($i=0; $i<count($col_name); $i++){

                    if($i==0) echo("'".$my_array[$col_name[$i]][$j]."'");
                    else echo($my_array[$col_name[$i]][$j]);
                    if($i< count($col_name)-1){
                        echo(",  ");
                    }
                }
                ?>
                ]
                <?php
                if($j<$n-1){
                    echo(",  ");
                }
            }
        ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title : 'Monthly Coffee ',
          vAxis: {title: "Cout"},
          hAxis: {title: "Jour"},
          seriesType: "bars",
          series: {<?php echo(count($col_name)-2) ?>: {type: "line"}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>



<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------> 

    </head>
    <table style="width: 1335px; height: 259px;" bgcolor="" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <div id="chart_div1" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><br>
    <p align='left'>From: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="log1" /> To: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="text1" /> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input></p></td></tr>
    <tr><td><br>
    <p><a href='ADMINISTRATION.php?'>Deconnexion</a></p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</html>
```

Comment: You just can't post your entire source code and expect someone to understand all of it and give you a solution. Please simplify and point to a specific problem you have

Comment: I have a pieChart with 2 slide and I want when I click in one slid, I can see a ComboChart. for this i use the " addListener " in my cod, but now i don't know how i can connecte the slids of piechart with my ComboChart, i don't know is it clear for you ??

Comment: @Arun it is not simplify for you?